# Array addition error

Tags: matlab

I wrote the following code for convolution in Matlab, but it gives me errors at notified lines. I am a beginner in Matlab so please bear with me answering this question.

```
function [y] = UmerConv(x,h)

xlen=length(x);
hlen=length(h);

p=1;
for j=1:xlen
    for k=1:hlen
        uinput{p}=x(j)*h(k);
        p=p+1;
    end
end

for i=1:hlen
    if(i==1 || i==hlen)
        y{i}=uinput(i);   // error
    else
        y{i}=uinput(i)+uinput(i+2); // error
    end
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You assign values into uinput with cell array syntax `{}`, but then later you index them with regular array syntax with `uinput(i)`. You have to keep it consistent. Using the curly braces `{}` makes the array a cell array, which is indexed differently than a regular array (which uses just parentheses).

You then also make the same assignment choice with the variable `y`, using the cell array syntax when it seems you'll probably want just regular array syntax.

The corrected code should probably be:

```
function [y] = UmerConv(x,h)

xlen=length(x);
hlen=length(h);

p=1;
for j=1:xlen
    for k=1:hlen
        uinput(p) = x(j)*h(k); % <-- Changed the {} syntax
        p=p+1;
    end
end

for i=1:hlen
    if(i==1 || i==hlen)
        y(i) = uinput(i);  % <-- Now you access both with () instead of {}
    else
        y(i) = uinput(i) + uinput(i+2); % <-- Same here.
    end
end
```

At each place where I noted a correction in a comment, you could alternately stick with solely the `{}` syntax, and then everything will work but the arrays will be cell arrays. Usually this is not desired for a such a numerical computation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `y(i)` instead that  `y{i}` to access the i-th position of a vector.

Comment: Note, this won't stop the error that occurs when the OP assigns into `uinput` with cell array syntax, but then later accesses it with regular array syntax.

Comment: That is, `y` will still end up as a cell array, and the later indexing with `()` will return cells, not the numeric contents.

Comment: @EMS Oh yes, sorry I jumped almost directly to the line the OP was pointing out and I assumed `uinput` was a normal array. I stand corrected.

Comment: @EMS +1 to your answer, by the way